# How to test light client on private testnet?

Tags: private-blockchain, light-clients

I am building a private testnet using Geth 1.5.6. I set up two nodes (**miner** and **user**) with two different datadir and listening port. **Miner** is a full node and mining blocks. **User** is just an ordinary node, syncing the blockchain and do some transactions. Both has the same custom genesis block. **User** connects to **miner** via it's enode URL.

When running in full node mode, **User** can connect to **miner** and sync the blockchain successfully. But, when I try the light client (LES) mode, **miner** is not responding to LES request and **user** is not syncing the blockchain. I am curious, how to correctly enable light server feature on **miner** so I can test the light client mode on private testnet? (**Note**: light client works flawlessly on Frontier and Ropsten).

Relevant parameters:

- **Miner**: `--lightserv 75 --lightpeers 100`
- **User**: `--light`
- Enabling Topic Discovery (`--v5disc`) on both nodes has no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to create static-nodes.json file in folder ".ethereum"

```
"enode://361caeb72dfbc1949a7ec3f19044996d4e6fe638b2e390f4dabfcc18e35a63163c313e7c67ee0c6a8a96e9e703b70c585b3bf6699f084794e9c2de13ad30137d@<lightserv_ip>:<port>",
"enode://77f5040352e1501598f0b25e39b402c509da478ff7f58428c24f8e0928368cfc4b845e2e307cd95a6f1468dcff8220fceaa1969565cc2bd8c07149496e39c9a1@<lightserv_ip>:<port>"
```

And restart geth, your node will be connected now.

https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/3510